# suddenly unable to boot into Kubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu, qt

I am suddenly unable to boot into Kubuntu, I didn't do anything weird to my system yesterday, and suddenly it does not boot, it gets stuck on the motherboards logo.
I've figured out already that when I Press alt+f2 I can get into the terminal, it seems like plasmashell does not want to boot, when I try to launch it I get the error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb could not connect to display.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimallegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb

fish: Job 1, 'plasmashell' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Is anyone able to help?
I've googled around and tried a few things and they sadly did not work.

I've had this before and fixed it by restoring a backup, but I don't want to keep restoring backups to keep my system working

Comment: When you didn't do anything weird, what normal things did you do before the error occured? Did your system get a software update?

Comment: @IngoSteinke yeah, just things I usually do, I did not update my system, or any software

Comment: But then it seems that Ubuntu linux can still boot, and you can enter a shell, but graphics mode does not work anymore? So probably you can use the shell session to get more detailed error logs, or else general system logs about any actions (updates, deletions, config changes, might be automatic or accidental) that occured after last time you were able to boot into the GUI.

Comment: how would I do that? I'm pretty new to daily driving linux

Comment: not sure, but I think the problem lies somewhere with `initramfs`  it seems to update when I install any package or something, but as soon as that gets changed or updated my system does not boot, I think I did update my system before, but I've been having similar issues before. I have a backup I can go back to, but as soon as I add a package, or try to fix anything, I get back to my current situation